# Why can't I edit and retag a certain question?

Tags: support, editing

I cannot edit and retag [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106662/19356) because their hyperlinks are disabled. Other questions have no problem. What makes the question above special?

The hyperlinks are alternately disabled and enabled as follows.

- Disabled
  [image]
- Disabled

  [image]
- Enabled
  [image]

Comment: Oh my ghost. Now the hyperlinks are enabled. Weird....

Comment: Ah... they are disabled again.

Comment: There where two edit suggestions around this time. You don't have over 2k rep, so you can only suggest edits yourself. I guess only one edit suggestion can be aktiv at the same time, and you simply have to wait until the previous suggestion was accepted.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: A great forensic attempt. You should make it as your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone else was editing the post at the same time?

Comment: Is it a by-design feature? In my experience, we can edit concurrently and the edit posted early will win.

Comment: :I have no idea what I'm doing here:    It was just a wild guess.  That or ghosts.  How 're you gonna call?

Comment: I usually use Skype to call.

Comment: But if there is something strange in the neighborhood?